# Android FFImageLoading! exception: System.Exception: Please call CachedImageRenderer.Init method in a platform specific

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, ffimageloading

I am getting this exception:
Unhandled Exception:
System.Exception: Please call CachedImageRenderer.Init method in a platform specific project to use FFImageLoading! occurred

The exception is occurring in external code and not code I can step through.

This exception only occurs in the Visual Studio Emulator for Android application.

But it works fine on a Samsung S8 phone.

My MainActvity code looks like:

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init(false);
        // etc
    }
```

I have tried various versions of the FFImageLoading library.  I am currently using the latest which is 2.4.7.944.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a few different emulated phones with the VS Android emulator and seeing that they worked I uninstalled the one that wasn't working and reinstalled it.  And now it is working properly.  The only thing I can say is arrrrrgh!